# How to convert a curve from 2D to 3D

Tags: bezier-curves, normals

I created a pattern out of straight lines in Illustrator and afterwards saved it as a SVG file. When I then imported the SVG file into Blender some of the lines appeared as 2D and some others as 3D.

[image: curve appearing as 3D]

[image]
Afterwards when I apply bevel object to that curve which is a bezier circle in this case the 3D curve looks great but the 2D curve looks like some of the normals have flipped direction. 
It still stays the same even when I try to make the curve 3D simply by clicking on 3D button.

[image: Upper curve has normals with flipped directions]

Could somebody tell me what is the problem here and how to solve it efficiently?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is. Could you share the blend file?